# Laravel 8 variable value from aggregate sum of multiple column values

Tags: php, laravel

I need to create a variable thats the aggregate sum of multiple values.  I have about 25 values to to add together--below is a small snippet.  The below works, but stringing all the values together with a `+` seems a bit dirty.  Is there another way?

```
// Calculate Modification Points
        $trackPTS = $this->track ? 20 : 0;
        $shockTowerPTS = $this->shock_tower ? 10 : 0;
        $loweringPTS = $this->lowering ? 10 : 0;
        $camberPTS = $this->camber ? 20 : 0;
        $monoballPTS = $this->monoball ? 10 : 0;
        $tubeFramePTS = $this->tube_frame ? 100 : 0;
        $pasmPTS = $this->pasm ? 20 : 0;
        $rearAxleSteerPTS = $this->rear_axle_steer ? 10 : 0;

        $totalModificationPoints = $treadWearPoints + $trackPTS + $shockTowerPTS + $loweringPTS + $camberPTS + $monoballPTS + $tubeFramePTS + $pasmPTS + $rearAxleSteerPTS;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one other way of doing the same thing.

```
$totalModificationPoints = 0; //initial value

$totalModificationPoints += $trackPTS = $this->track ? 20 : 0;
$totalModificationPoints += $shockTowerPTS = $this->shock_tower ? 10 : 0;
$totalModificationPoints += $loweringPTS = $this->lowering ? 10 : 0;
$totalModificationPoints += $camberPTS = $this->camber ? 20 : 0;
$totalModificationPoints += $monoballPTS = $this->monoball ? 10 : 0;
$totalModificationPoints += $tubeFramePTS = $this->tube_frame ? 100 : 0;
$totalModificationPoints += $pasmPTS = $this->pasm ? 20 : 0;
$totalModificationPoints += $rearAxleSteerPTS = $this->rear_axle_steer ? 10 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put all possible class variable names to an array and then i would iterate it. Like that:

```php
<?php
class Calc {
 
  private $track = 30;
  private $shock_tower = 40;
  private $lowering = 10;
  
  public function __construct() {    
    $keyValues = [
        ['track', 20],
        ['shock_tower', 10],
        ['lowering', 10],
    ];

    $sum = 0;
    foreach($keyValues as $set) {        
        $sum += (int) $this->{$set[0]} ?? $set[1];
    }

    print_r($sum);
  }
}

new Calc();
```